# Python: pyodbc insert in SQL list of lists (or similar bulk upload without using insertmany)

Tags: python, sql, insert, pyodbc

My aim is to take a column (1mn rows) from SQL table, make some calculations in python and insert it back into another table in SQL. Current code does line by line calculations and line by line insertion to SQL. 100,000 rows takes 180sec (which I was told is slow). I want a single insertion for 1mn rows. I searched here and found many solutions that did not work. I work on Python2.7.

Solution1 that did not work:

```
args = [['a','b','1'],['c','d','2'],['e','f','3']]
temp = ['%s','%s','%s']
numRows = 3
InsertSQL = "INSERT INTO SB.Temp VALUES" + ','.join(['('+','.join(temp)+')']*numRows)
c.execute(InsertSQL,args)
conn.commit()
```

Error:

```
ProgrammingError: ('The SQL contains 0 parameter markers, 
but 3 parameters were supplied', 'HY000')
```

I am a python NOOB, so I had retro engineer the string that is needed for SQL and came up with this solution that does work, but it is not elegant.

```
def itworks():
    args = [['a','b','1'],['c','d','2'],['e','f','3']]
    nargs = []
    for i in args:
        nargs.append("('{}', '{}', {})".format(i[0],i[1],i[2]))
        nargs = ','.join(nargs)

    c.execute ("INSERT INTO SB.Temp VALUES {}".format(nargs))
    conn.commit()
```

I have 2 questions:
 - What is the best efficient way to insert a million lines into SQL in one go?
 - How to make my solution more 'pythony'?
THANK YOU!
Alex

Comment: As you might have noticed, first 2 items in little lists must be strings, but the third item is integer. But join didn't work with integers, so I had to change them into strings until they are inserted into SQL query.

Comment: 2 quick questions:  (1) Are all of the calculations/operations Python required, or can you do them in the DB?  (2) It looks like you're inserting into a permanent table named SB.Temp, but you're not specifying any columns to insert into, is this a typo or incorrect SQL syntax?

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response.
1 - I guess the answer is "no", but as a matter of learning python I would like to. however I would like to explore ways to make this directly in the DB
2 - yes it is weird, but it does work even without specifying column names, I am sure if I write them in the query it will keep working.

Comment: I tried to actually implement my way and found another problem:

ProgrammingError: ('42000', '[42000] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]The number of row value expressions in the INSERT statement exceeds the maximum allowed number of 1000 row values.  (10738) (SQLExecDirectW)')

So, it seems that I can only insert 1000 rows...strange

Comment: Usually, in these scenarios with tremendous amounts of data, running an iterative insert by looping over your data list is going to be faster because it only holds a small amount of data in memory as it runs the loop.  Is your time above of 180 Seconds the time it took to fetch, calculate/operate, and load, or just the load time?

Comment: *"So, it seems that I can only insert 1000 rows...strange"* - No, it is a well-documented limit of the Table Value Constructor (ref: [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd776382.aspx)). Still, if you insert 10^6 rows in 1000 batches of 1000 rows each it would probably be an improvement over 10^6 batches of 1 row each.

Comment: Thanks @dblclik,180 seconds for the whole operation, correct. So it is to fetch 100k rows from MSSQL, then run 100k loop to apply changes and to insert it to a fresh table, finally commit outside of the loop.

Comment: Thanks @GordThompson, Yes this is my next task, to come up with a batching technique, to split the fetchall into 1000 row batches. As you see I am still learning basic programming stuff and this kind of problems are great opportunity.